# Android, not connecting to local php file

Tags: android

I'm trying to have my android app execute code where it opens a URL connection to a local php file that returns database entries in JSON format, but it's not connecting, after commenting out the other lines I can see that it throws an exception at the lines:

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
```

Heres the screen shot of android code and the error log, the returned expected json file in windows and the php file:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edq8g.png)

Comment: Please do not use images for your code, we can't copy it, try to duplicate your problem, and links die overtime, preventing anyone from knowing what youre asking

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your

```
URL url = new URL(getListUrl);
```

into

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
```

and check the incoming data.

and the following is a working example.

```
      try {
     URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
     URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

     if (!(urlConn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
        throw new IOException("URL Exception");
     }
     HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
     httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
     httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
     httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
     httpConn.connect();
     resCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

     if (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        in = httpConn.getInputStream();
     }
  }

  catch (MalformedURLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

My argument is if this code works for remote urls, it should work with localhost as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it must be that you are using wrong local ip address in android files
it should be 10.0.2.2 not 127.0.0.1

First tell me are you testing on emulator or device

if emulator then where you define file path it should be 
http://10.0.2.2/request_entries.php

just like in code

```
httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/request_entries.php");
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: sorry my comments are blocked

Comment: I'm testing on an emulator

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get the input stream using the URL:

```
URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/request_entries.php");
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0aN7.png)

Thanks a bunch guys :)